# Find $\mathbb{R}_l \cap \mathbb{R}_K$

Tags: general-topology

Find $\mathbb{R}_l \cap \mathbb{R}_K$, where $\mathbb{R}_l$ is the lower limit topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}_K$ is the K-topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Is the intersection an empty set? I can't think of a set that is open in both topologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every open set in the usual topology on $\mathbb R$ is open in the lower limit topology and also in the $K$- topology on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: But this only shows that $\mathbb R \subset \mathbb R_l \cap \mathbb R_K$, it may not be all of them.

Comment: @YuiToCheng  Yes, so then we still have to show that any set which is not open in stadard topology is not open in  K topology or lower limit topology